# Generating json schema with fasterxml 2.2.0 - How to reference types?

Tags: json, ref, jsonschema, fasterxml

I'm using the fasterxml json framework version 2.2.0 in order to create the schema in json of the API of the app I'm working on.

My API is similar to : https://gist.github.com/nemo83/5555249

Where Customer and Order both have a reference to Address. Now, when I attempt to generate the schema (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema) the result is:

{"type":"object","properties":{"address":{"type":"object","properties":{"addressLine2":{"type":"string"},"addressLine1":{"type":"string"}}},"customer":{"type":"object","properties":{"address":{"type":"object","properties":{"addressLine2":{"type":"string"},"addressLine1":{"type":"string"}}},"name":{"type":"string"}}}}}

As you can see the Adress is not represented as a type, but both Customer and Order flatten it in their description.

Is there a way to instruct fasterxml schema generation to address this issue and make use of the "$ref" property for properly reference the Address object?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to jackson-module-jsonSchema 4.1 version where they've resolved this issue and also enabled self referencing classes schema generation possible.